# How to create database schema (table) in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel

I'm new to Laravel.I'm trying to create database in Laravel. I tried in console with:

```php
Schema::create
```

But it's giving 'command not found'. What should I install or how to create database?

Comment: You should read the [Laravel Migrations Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations) in detail to see how to work with migrations and create tables in your database.

Comment: I saw from here - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema -it's written to use: `Schema::create` to create database but it's giving me command not found.

Comment: `Schema::create` will create a table in your database, not the actual database (also you're looking at the documentation for Laravel 4.2 when you should be looking the [Laravel 5 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/schema)) . Laravel migrations are not really meant to create databases, just to create structure inside them. You could use `DB::statement` to create the database but since the Schema Builder is intended to be database agnostic it isn't build in that way. You should specify what database you are using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc) so we can provide guidance on how to create the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set database name,username and password in database.php in config folder.it look like

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'news'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],
```

if you are using xampp then right click on your project folder and click on use composer here

then run following command

```
 php artisan migrate:install
```

and  you can create table like

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

**Migration Structure**

A migration class contains two methods: up and down. The up method is used to add new tables, columns, or indexes to your database, while the down method should simply reverse the operations performed by the up method.

Within both of these methods you may use the Laravel schema builder to expressively create and modify tables. To learn about all of the methods available on the Schema builder, check out its documentation. For example, let's look at a sample migration that creates a flights table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFlightsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('flights');
    }
}
```

To know all artisan command run following command

```
php artisan
```

for more read following document http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations

Comment: The question is about creating database which is not addressed in this response.

Comment: The answer only reflects on how to create tables, not databases.

Comment: I don't know why is this accepted as the right answer. The question was about how to create a database and not a table structure inside database.

Comment: Yes, the question is about creating databse, not creating tables...
So I'm also confused why this was accepted as the right answer...

Answer (score 34):

my working example:

create new artisan command:

```
php artisan make:command mysql
```

the content of App\Console\Commands\mysql.php :

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class mysql extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'mysql:createdb {name?}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create a new mysql database schema based on the database config file';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $schemaName = $this->argument('name') ?: config("database.connections.mysql.database");
        $charset = config("database.connections.mysql.charset",'utf8mb4');
        $collation = config("database.connections.mysql.collation",'utf8mb4_unicode_ci');

        config(["database.connections.mysql.database" => null]);

        $query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $schemaName CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collation;";

        DB::statement($query);

        config(["database.connections.mysql.database" => $schemaName]);

    }
}
```

then run: (schema_name is optionally)

```
php artisan mysql:createdb schema_name
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I had an issue where migrate run was just failing with an already created database. I dropped it and used this to create it before clearing cache and re-installing migrate, and this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I run "php artisan make:command mysql", it returns "Console command already exists!" I run "php artisan mysql:createdb", it returns "There are no commands defined in the "mysql" namespace."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create model with artisan do it this way:

```
php artisan make:model ModelName
```

Comment: Yes, I see these tutorials and I've watched them to migrations. It is explained how to create model and tables, but how to create database? :)

Comment: It depends what you mean by creating database, do you want to create actual database (mysql or anything alse)?

Comment: Yes, mysql database and after that I'll create the tables

Comment: Do you have any Apache server installed (e.g. XAMPP) you should go to phpmyadmin and create database there, watch this for further reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dV3JjLhi4Jk

Comment: Thank you everybody! I thought there was a way through console. I'll create it from phpmyadmin. and set configuration in env file :)

Comment: Yes you can do it, see here: "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-database.html", but as you are a beginner, I thought it would be easier that way, just note that if you are going to do it via CLI, you will have to find right port for your connection.

Answer (score 1):

### Database setup in Laravel

- open `.env` file on root

example :-

```
  DB_CONNECTION=mysql
  DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
  DB_PORT=3306
  DB_DATABASE=dbname
  DB_USERNAME=root
  DB_PASSWORD=password
```

> Now run command

```
  php artisan migrate:install
  php artisan make:migration users // for creating new table
```