# How in laravel it is possible to check up, whether there is a database, and if not that to create?

Tags: laravel

I want to do something similar to a database backup if something happens. Before restoring, I want to check if the database exists at all. I tried to do like this

```
DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_name');
```

but this only works if the database name does not match the database the laravel is configured for. And it is necessary that it be restored. and in this case

```
  Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'db_name'
```

this mistake. How can you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
try {
    if (Schema::hasTable('users'))
        return('Connection Established');
    else
        return ('No luck');

} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    //This means there is definitely error connecting to database
    return('PDO Exception, check log.');
}
```

Comment: A bit wrong. I just need to check if the base is in general. If there is but empty, that's okay, further in the method there is a recovery. And if not at all, then you need to create an empty one. Can you help how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Testing extends Controller
{
   public function get()
   {
        $query = "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME =  ?";
        $db = DB::select($query, [$your_database_name]);
        if (empty($db)) {
            echo 'No db exist of that name!';
        } else {
            echo 'db already exists!';
        }
```

and for creating database with laravel i think this link will help you:
[How to create database schema (table) in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191135/how-to-create-database-schema-table-in-laravel)